# How will light refract if it falls at the corner of a rectangular glass slab

Tags: refraction, glass

my friend asked me a question related to the refraction of light at the corner of a glass slab.

[image]

How will light behave in this situation? My thinking is that AB will be the surface and AC will act as a normal and light will bend towards it. But the thing is, it is falling at exactly the place where sides AC and AB of this rectangular glass slab meet so I think this might not be the solution of what is going to happen. Also please try to explain in a simple way (I'm in high school).

Answer (score 1):

You have drawn a single ray. But that isn't all of the light. Light is a wave, and waves are spread out. You draw rays to show the direction the wave is traveling.

Some of the wave will hit side AB and some will hit AC. Each side will refract light. So the wave or rays that travel through the top will bend to a direction closer to vertical. Those through the side will bend more horizontally. The two waves will pass through each other.

What happens at the corner is an example of what is called a "corner case". It is a sort of an exception to a rule that applies almost everywhere.

In this case, you might think about microscopic details of the corner. If the corner was infinitely sharp, the size of the exception would be $0$. It generally isn't.

But that isn't really the way to go. Light is a wave that usually travels in straight lines. Rays describe the straight line behavior. But rays are an approximation to the truth. Waves are more complex than that. For example, they bend around obstacles.

To see this kind of wave behavior, you have to look at objects somewhere near the wavelength of light. The wavelength of visible light is about $0.0005$ mm. You begin to see diffraction if you pass light through a slit $0.5$ mm wide. Or if you look very closely at the edge of a wider slit. This is called [knife edge diffraction](https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/presentations/edge-diffraction).

[image]

So if you want to know the details of how light behaves at a sharp corner, you have to use a wave description of light, and ask what diffraction pattern you will see. That can be done, but the calculation is beyond high school physics. See the Wikipedia article on [Diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction) for more.

You might think about it in an approximate way by considering a wall with an AC window in it. You would expect to see something like a knife edge diffraction pattern if you look closely at A. Add that to a similar diffraction pattern you would get from an AB window. That isn't really right, because the two together would interfere with each other. But it gives the flavor of the answer.

Comment: So I think the best answer here for me would be that there is an answer, but it's beyond my current understanding and I can go with the general solution that at atomic levels some things might be happening, changing the results